# Method cannot be applied to given types Program09

Tags: java, methods, compilation

I made this program as a project for one of my classes, and upon compiling it, I get this error:

> Program09.java:21: error: method calculateCelsius in class Program09 cannot be applied to given types;
>              double cTemp = calculateCelsius();
>                             ^
>     required: int
>     found: no arguments
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   Program09.java:24: error: method calculateCelsius in class Program09 cannot be applied to given types;
>             calculateCelsius();
>             ^
>     required: int
>     found: no arguments
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   Program09.java:25: error: method displayResults in class Program09 cannot be applied to given types;
>             displayResults();
>             ^
>     required: int,double
>     found: no arguments
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   3 errors

This is the program below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program09
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       int fTemp = getFarenheit();
       double cTemp = calculateCelsius();
      displayInstructions();
      getFarenheit();
      calculateCelsius();
      displayResults();
   }
   public static void displayInstructions()
   {
       System.out.println("This program will convert farenheit to celsius");
       System.out.println("after you enter a farenheit temperature");
   }
   public static int getFarenheit()
   {
       System.out.println("Please enter your temperature below");
       Scanner keyboard = new  Scanner(System.in);
       return keyboard.nextInt();
   }
   public static double calculateCelsius(int farenheit)
   {
       return (5 * (farenheit - 32) / 9.0);
   }
   public static void displayResults(int fTemp, double cTemp)
   {
       System.out.println("Your farenheit temperature is " + fTemp);
       System.out.printf("Your celsius temperature is ", + cTemp);
       System.out.println("Thank you for using the program!");
       System.out.println("The rest of the world needs to conform to imperial measurments, cuz 'merica");
       return;

   }       
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Your calling calculateCelsius without a parameter, you need to pass your parameter correctly, like this.

```
int fTemp = getFarenheit();
double cTemp = calculateCelsius(fTemp);
```

additionally displayResults will also fail for the same reason, pass in fTemp and cTemp when calling it